# How to convert a query hash to uint64?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

How do I convert the query hash string "0x9F37D9B585242D49" to a uint64 needed by my extended event filter?  Casting to bigint doesn't work as the value goes negative.

```
event
sql_statement_completed

filter
field : sqlserver.query_hash
operator : equal_uint64
value ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSQL doesn't have unsigned 64bit integers, but .NET does.

```
var hash = 0x9F37D9B585242D49;
Console.WriteLine(hash);
```

outputs

```
11472877949395676489
```

And you also can filter on `query_hash_signed` and provide a singed 64bit integer, which TSQL can produce

```
select cast(0x9F37D9B585242D49 as bigint)
```

outputs

```
-6973866124313875127
```